# Instalador al descargar MYSQL

Tags: mysql

descargue mysql desde su web pero el archivo zip descargado solo muestra varias carpetas con archivos , mas no un instalador, solicito ayuda para el proceso de instalacion; intente copiarlo en c pero tampoco funciona
gracias

Comment: Asegúrate que el archivo que descargaste coincida con la versión de tu sistema operativo. Si usas windows, busca el instalador.

Comment: Desde [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) puedes descargar todas las versiones del `MySQL Community Server`

Answer (score 2):

Descargaste el zip y no el instalador, el instalador es el siguiente:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaria utilizar otro programa, por ejemplo Uwamp, alli puedes hacer un localhost y viene incluido con PHPMyAdmin, si necesitas mas ayuda o necesitas otras opciones, yo con gusto si tu lo pides, te adjunto un manual mas tarde.

http://www.uwamp.com/en/?page=download

Comment: ademas de que en phpmyadmin puedes crear una base de datos y tambien tablas

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, verifica este enlace `https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/`
Debes descargar el instalador como tal, al estae en la pagina, verifica el sistema operativo y posteriormente descargas el adecuado para ti, en la siguiente ventana solo das click en **No thanks, just start my download.** para que comience la descarga y listo....
Espero te sea de ayuda... saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como comentaron anteriormente, no bajaste el paquete o el instalador. pero es necesario saber ¿Qué sistema operativo utilizas?, si necesitas una integración de desarrollo completa como LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySql y PHP) y utilizas windows hay varios paquetes que te integran esta solción como: XAMPP o WAMP. Si utilizas Linux hay paquetes que te instalan la solución completa sin tener que insalar componente por componente. En Ubuntu puedes utilizar:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```